# Using linq to return records from sql server based on users datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, linq, datetimeoffset

I have a dateTime offset value that gets passed from the UI which looks like

startDate:2022-04-25 21:08:02.2973333 +00:00 but the date i entered is actually the 26th

i want to get the records from the db for everything before the 26th and equal to the 26th.

this is what i tried

```
await _repository.GetProjectedListAsync(q=>q.Where(x => x.Created <= DateTime.Parse( query.StartDate.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") ).Select(FirstName))).ToList();
```

the created column in sql looks like the following

[image: Created column]

the above conversion didnt work,it doesnt return any results.
Is there a way i could convert the repected date to return the records **where Created <= Startdate** ?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse( query.StartDate.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`, look like you are casting DateTime to string and then compare with date. Try to remove  `.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`.

Comment: @YongShun i tried this now and it still doesnt get me any records back

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see the code:

```
var textDate = DateTime.Parse(query.StartDate.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

await _repository.GetProjectedListAsync(q => 
    q.Where(x => x.Created <= startDate)
       .Select(FirstName)))
    .ToList();
```

If you have a variable with the same value, it's better parse outside. Then, you only do the parse once. If you look textDate:

- Take StartDate and convert to string.
- Then, parse to date.
- And convert again to string.

This sentence do nothing because you convert to string and back to date:

```
DateTime.Parse(query.StartDate.ToString())
```

So we have:

```
var textDate = query.StartDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

I suppose you want work only with date (without time)

```
var startDate = query.StartDate.Date
```

If I'm not wrong, you want something like this:

```
var startDate = query.StartDate.Date
await _repository.GetProjectedListAsync(q => 
    q.Where(x => x.Created <= startDate)
       .Select(FirstName)))
    .ToList();
```